# How to change the value of radio buttons using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Say I have this radio:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2"> 2
</form>
```

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
document.myForm.foo.value = "2";
```

In order to dynamically select the 2nd radio button. Or a way to do the following using jquery.

Comment: Isn't the value of the 2nd radio button already 2??

Comment: So, do you want to cause a radio where the value is 2 to be selected, or do you want to change the value of the second radio button to 2?  Your question is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selector:

```
$('input[value="2"][name="foo"]')
```

Comment: what if I have more than 1 radios or inputs?

Comment: What if I have more than one sets of radios who both have values of 2? e.g `<input name = foo value = 2 /> and <input name = bar value = 2 />` and I want to only select the foo one

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Answer updated to match two selectors as per request.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('[name="foo"]').val(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you requested this way, you could do:

`document.myForm.foo[1].checked = true;  //selects the 2nd radio button`

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bTzqw/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `$(':radio[name=foo]:eq(1)')`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Dk6sB/)

Answer (score 0):

If you grab all your radios by name in a jQuery collection, then you can select by index with `eq()`.

```
$('input[name="foo"]').eq(1) // 2nd input
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByName('foo')[1].check();//Or .checked = true
```

Comment: Won't work because what if I want to move the radio options around?

Comment: If you want something that addresses that question it should be part of your original question.

Comment: it's just a fast example that shows you can select it by his name. So, the better solutiuon is to keep the same name but set different ids, like option1 and option2